# "Column not found" when selecting from a table in a different schema

Tags: sql, database, h2

I'm experiencing a very weird issue with H2.

In addition to all the tables residing in default ("PUBLIC") schema, I have several tables created in a separate schema (there's a valid business reason to do it that way, but it's irrelevant here). When I run

```
select * from schema1.table1
```

everything works perfectly. If I try to do the same but mention the column name(s) explicitly, e.g.

```
select col1, col2 from schema1.table1
```

the query fails with "Column col1 not found; 42S22/42122" error. This occurs whenever the column is referenced anywhere in select (from clause / where clause / etc...).

Column names are correct and they show up in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Furthermore, if I quote them, query works properly - however this has a side effect of making column names case sensitive which then fails in Hibernate which apparently uppercases them anyway.

Am I overlooking something obvious here? Is there a reason for this bizarre behavior or is this a bug?

**Update**: Thomas's answer made me realize that the issue was not with a different schema but rather with how tables in that schema were created; specifically the use of quoted identifiers. Here's a script that reproduces the problem in H2 1.3.161 (latest version atm):

```
create table table1(col1 int, "col2" int);
insert into table1 values(1, 1);
select * from table1; -- works
select col1 from table1; -- works
select "col2" from table1; -- works
select col2 from table1; -- fails
```

I don't understand why there's a difference between the last 2 queries. Column name is case-sensitive here (because it was defined via quoted identifier), but it does have the correct case. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` shows no differences (aside from name) between the two columns either. Is case insensivity for unquoted columns obtained by forcibly uppercasing all queries?

The above script works as expected (as in all queries complete successfully) in Postgres.

Comment: "database" is generic - h2 is a specific database, which is why I typically remove the tag when combined with mysql, oracle, etc.  I forgot to add the sql tag...

Comment: @OMG Ponies - "database" is generic, but it also has a lot more subscribers. And while this indeed seems to be an H2-specific issue, somebody may have come across something similar in another database. Thank you for adding "sql" - I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem. Could you post a complete, reproducible problem? I ran the following script in the H2 Console, and it works (meaning, I get no exception):

```
drop all objects;
create schema schema1;
create table schema1.table1(col1 int, col2 int);
insert into schema1.table1 values(1, 1);
select * from schema1.table1;
select col1, col2 from schema1.table1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Thomas. It made me realize that the problem was actually with quoted identifiers used during table creation. I've updated my question above and included complete script for reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in my case I was incorrectly using `"` instead of `'` in the query